# Gradle sync failed - Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to import an existing project (sample project by apigee) into Android Studio 3.0.1. I get the following error:

> Gradle sync failed: No signature of method: org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.allowPackage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.apache.tools.zip]

Note: I *did* change the graddle-wrapper.properties file entry from `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip` as I was facing an earlier error.

The Gradle version in Project Structure is also 4.1.

Here are some excerpts from the logs:

```
2017-11-21 19:45:01,324 [se-915-b01]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 875 ms 
2017-11-21 19:45:02,350 [ thread 20]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
....
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\apigee-android-sdk-2.0.14\source\build.gradle' line: 2
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'apigee-android'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
......
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'apigee-android'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
....
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowBasePlugin']
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:150)
....
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.allowPackage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.apache.tools.zip]
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowBasePlugin.apply(ShadowBasePlugin.groovy:36)
......
2017-11-21 19:45:02,361 [ thread 20]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - No signature of method: org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.allowPackage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.apache.tools.zip] 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.LocationAwareExternalSystemException: No signature of method: org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.allowPackage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.apache.tools.zip]
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:81)
......
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.allowPackage() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.apache.tools.zip]
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowBasePlugin.apply(ShadowBasePlugin.groovy:36)
```

Comment: Can we see your build.gradle file?